# Inserir texto com imagem em um LIstItem do Sharepoint

Tags: c#, wpf, sharepoint

Faço a criação de itens no SharePoint, com um app WPF/C#, como no exemplo:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using SP = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

namespace Microsoft.SDK.SharePointServices.Samples
{
    class CreateListItem
    {
        static void Main()
        {   
            string siteUrl = "http://MyServer/sites/MySiteCollection";

            ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
            SP.List oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Announcements");

            ListItemCreationInformation itemCreateInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();
            ListItem oListItem = oList.AddItem(itemCreateInfo);
            oListItem["Title"] = "My New Item!";
            oListItem["Body"] = "Hello World!";

            oListItem.Update();

            clientContext.ExecuteQuery(); 
        }
    }
}
```

A questão é que na coluna "Body", eu teria que inserir um conteúdo vindo de um RichTextBox, onde é possível inserir textos com imagens.

Não encontrei uma forma de inserir o texto e imagens, adicionadas como num documento word, a essa coluna. Obter o conteúdo do RTB com o textRange resulta na conversão da imagem para hexadecimal, o que não me serve.

Eu sei que talvez seja necessário salvar as imagens em um diretório dentro do sharepoint e referenciá-las no texto, como um index ou algo assim, porém não encontrei documentação e não faço ideia de como fazer.

Comment: O seu problema é em definir o ListItem como RichText ou fazer a leitura e conversão do documento word?

Comment: Meu problema está em converter o conteúdo de um Richtextbox, que está na minha aplicação, para a coluna do ListItem do SP. Se fosse somente texto, seria tranquilo, como no exemplo. Mas, como o Richtextbox na minha aplicação pode conter imagens junto ao texto, não sei como inserir esses dados.

Comment: qual tipo de texto o sharepoint aceita ? poderia mandar html ?

Comment: Ele aceita html, porém, se for mandar um html eu teria que identificar as imagens em meio ao texto, fazer upload delas para uma pasta dentro do sharepoint, para então ser possível referenciá-las no conteúdo html